# Using instance_eval to execute a block

Tags: ruby

I have the following class `MyClass`.

```
  class MyClass
   def initialize(&block)
     if block_given?
      self.instance_eval &block
      p "Hey #{@name}, I have a message for you: #{@message}"
     else
      #do_something else
     end
   end

  def say(message)
   @message = message
   #puts "how are you"
  end

  def to(name)
   puts self.inspect
   @name = name
  end

end
```

I call this class with `MyClass.new { say('Hello').to('Haseeb') }`. But it throws me this error.

```
 undefined method `to' for "Hello":String (NoMethodError).
```

The output should be `Hey Haseeb I have a message for you: Hello`

Comment: _Sidenote_: this is by no means a `metaprogramming`.

Comment: It is written above. How to not have this error occur and have the desired output.

Comment: The downvote was not justified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to chain methods ⇒ return a receiver (`self`):

```
def say(message)
  @message = message
  self
end
```

In current implementation, `say` method returns a string and you are calling `to` method on returned value (a `String` instance,) resulting in error.

Comment: Okay so returning`self` in the `message` method returning the `#<MyClass>` object which has an implementation of `to` method` defined. Correct? Since `String#to` doesn't exist.

Comment: I am lost. There is no `message` method defined. The receiver of `to` is supposed to be `MyClass` instance ⇒ return it from `say` method that is chained before. I can’t restate it more clear.

Comment: Oh my bad, The method `say` I meant. Not `message`. Thanks a ton!